# Differentiation Operator a Contraction Mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $C^{\infty}[a,b]$ be the space of all infinitely differentiable functions on [a,b] with norm $$ || f || = \max _{[0,1]} | f(x) | , f \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$$

Is the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ a contraction mapping on $C^{\infty}[a,b]$?

I'm confused. Operators are not until later in the textbook, and the contraction mappings I've worked with are using the Mean Value Theorem which are referencing a derivative? Ah!

Comment: Questions for you: (1) What is the definition of contraction mapping? That is, what exactly is the property you're trying to see whether or not $\frac{d}{dx}$ has? (2) Have you tried some examples of functions $f$ in the space, computing the norms of $f$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$, to gather evidence as to whether or not it is plausible?

Comment: Don't worry about the word "operator".  It is just asking about the map $f\mapsto f'$ from $C^\infty[a,b]$ to itself.

Comment: I know intuitively it is a mapping that when we're measuring distance in one space (a norm) brings the things closer together for all elements in the interval (so we say it is a contraction mapping on this interval or subset?). The actual definition from my textbook is $||Ax, Ay|| \leq \alpha ||x, y||$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ then A is a contraction. should I just try for any smooth function?

Comment: Questioner: You mean $\|Ax-Ay\|\leq\alpha\|x-y\|$?  I would suggest trying a variety of simple examples of functions, or drawing pictures, to see what is going on, how $\|f\|$ and $\|\frac{df}{dx}\|$ are related.  A rougher version of the question is: If $f$ is small, must $\frac{df}{dx}$ be small?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jonas. I first thought of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$, the magnitude or amplitude of these functions will not decrease after a derivative. I would think that would be enough just in the Euclidean space with the standard distance, how do I incorporate this norm?

Comment: Aahhh, so I will take the norm of say $sin$ and $cos$, and then take the norm of $d/dx sin$ and $d/dx cos$ and show that it is not necessarily always contracted?

Comment: Questioner: (I don't understand your last sentence of your second to last comment.  There is no Euclidean distance really, just the definition of the norm given in the question, unless you are referring to the absolute value applied pointwise as the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb R$).  $\sin$ and $\cos$ are good examples to start with.  You may need to shift and scale appropriately.  And yes, if there is a counterexample, it can be shown as you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a contraction.

Let $f(x)=\sin nx$, $g(x)=\cos nx$ ($n$ is a number we need to find). Then $f,g\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$. And
\begin{align*}
\left\|f-g\right\|=&\underset{[a,b]}{\max}|\sin nx-\cos nx|=\sqrt{2}\underset{[a,b]}{\max}|\sin(nx-\frac{\pi}{4})|
\\
\left\|\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{dg}{dx}\right\|=&\left\|n\cos nx+n\sin nx\right\|=n\underset{[a,b]}{\max}|\cos nx+\sin nx|=\sqrt{2}n\underset{[a,b]}{\max}|\sin(nx+\frac{\pi}{4})|
\end{align*}
If we take $n$ large enough that $n\ge\frac{2\pi}{b-a}$, then
\begin{align*}
\left\|f-g\right\|=\sqrt{2},\qquad\left\|\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{dg}{dx}\right\|=\sqrt{2}n.
\end{align*}
If we also make $n\ge1$,
$$\left\|\frac{df}{dx}-\frac{dg}{dx}\right\|\ge\left\|f-g\right\|.$$
Therefore the operator $d/dx$ is not contraction.